# Constructing graph using nodes and vertices based on some data

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, dictionary, graph

I am working with directed graphs given by an adjacency representation. In other words a graph G will be represented by a dictionary whose keys are the vertices and whose values are dictionaries whose keys are the neighbors of a vertex, the values of which may be assigned to 1. Given two vertices u, v in a directed graph G there may be an edge from u to v but not vice versa. It is however possible that there is an edge in both directions.

I have created a function called reachable_vertices which will take a graph G and vertex v, as input and returns a list of all the vertices in G which can be reached from v. If a vertex w can be reached by v this means that there is a chain v → v1 → v2... → w where there is an edge from each vertex in the chain to the one immediately after it. The vertex v does not have to have a particular type such as int or string, it could be either of these, it need only be a key in the dictionary representing the graph G.

I have deﬁned a function called cfb_graph which takes no arguments. I formed a directed graph from the ﬁle cfb2010.csv (Link Below) by considering the teams as vertices and creating an edge between team1 and team2 only if team1 defeated team2.
Data Set Link =https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZgNjH_QE7if1xHMfRU2-ebd9bNpL2E3d

cfb_graph will return a dictionary giving this representation.

I was able to find the following questions for which I am attaching my code below:
i. Which teams are not reachable from Auburn. Store them in a list. 
ii. Which teams are reachable from Notre Dame. Store them in a list.
iii. Which teams are not reachable from Alabama. Store them in a list.

I am working on the following code:

```
def reachable(G, v, setA): # This function checks if it's possible to reach w from v
    setA|={v}
    try:
        for w in set(G[v])-setA:reachable(G,w,setA)
    except KeyError:
        donothing = 0   
    return setA    
##   2a ##
def reachable_vertices(G, v):
    setA=set()
    setA|={v}
    try:
        for n in set(G[v])-setA:reachable(G,n,setA)
    except KeyError:
        donothing = 0    
    return setA    

def cfb_graph():
    svertex = []
    evertex = []
    count= 0
    file = open("cfb2010.csv","r")
    for line in file:  
        fields = line.split(",")
        if fields[5].replace("\n", "") == 'W':
            svertex.append(fields[1])
            evertex.append(fields[2])
        if count == 0:
            count = count +1


    graph = {}
    for i in range(len(svertex)):
        v = svertex[i]
        if v in graph:
            graph[v] |= set([evertex[i]])
        else:
            graph[v] = set([evertex[i]])    

    for key, value in graph.items():
          graph[key] =  dict.fromkeys(value,1) 
    return(graph)


######Part 2 c############
auburn_answer = list(set(cfb_graph().keys()).difference(set(reachable_vertices(cfb_graph(), "Auburn"))))
notre_dame_answer = reachable_vertices(cfb_graph(), "Notre Dame")
alabama_answer = list(set(cfb_graph().keys()).difference(set(reachable_vertices(cfb_graph(), "Alabama"))))
```

In particular for each vertex I want to return a dictionary where the keys are the reachable vertices and the values are as will now be described. If a vertex w is reachable from a vertex v there is a path from v to w. The value corresponding to w in the returned dictionary will be the vertex which immediately preceeds it in some path from v to w. If I use the queue approach then the value of w would the ﬁrst vertex u in the while loop for which w is a neighbor of u.

Also, I want to deﬁne a function called path which will take as input a graph G and two vertices v and w. If w is reachable from v it will return a list of vertices whose ﬁrst element is v and whose last element is w and the other vertices are those on a path from v to w in the order in which they are traversed. If there is no path I should return None. I will probably want to use the function defined above.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://www.python.org/doc/essays/graphs/

Comment: What you are doing (or trying to do) is called a Breadth First Search (BFS), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search. In the exploration, you usually store parent reference, which effectively let you draw the path to link any pair of nodes.

Comment: How can I program it

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the fast and powerful graph processing library [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) will help you a lot. It has the huge amount of various algorithms so you can not to implement it manually, but just use a function call in your code.

I constructed a small workflow that copies all your functionality and solves your problems:

```
# Imports
import networkx as nx
import csv

# Load CSV file and construct the directed graph
G = nx.DiGraph()
with open('cfb2010.csv', 'r') as f:
    sreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for line in sreader:
        if line[-1] != 'W':
            continue
        G.add_node(line[1])
        G.add_node(line[2])
        G.add_edge(line[1], line[2])

# Get all nodes
all_nodes = set(G.nodes())

# Get nodes that can be reached from the particular node
notredame_nodes = set(nx.bfs_tree(G, 'Notre Dame').nodes())
alabama_nodes = set(nx.bfs_tree(G, 'Alabama').nodes())
auburn_nodes = set(nx.bfs_tree(G, 'Auburn').nodes())

# Construct lists of nodes you need
print(all_nodes - alabama_nodes)
print(all_nodes - auburn_nodes)
print(notredame_nodes)
```

Networkx also has a function equals to your *function called path* function:

```
print(nx.shortest_path(G, 'Florida', 'Illinois'))

['Florida', 'Penn St', 'Michigan', 'Illinois']
```

P.S. Reachable nodes construction uses [BFS algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).